# How to close google pay dialog programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, google-pay

In business logic we have a timer So if timer runs out we need to stop user from paying using google pay. For that we want to dismiss google pay dialog programmatically. We dont find any solution in this sample project. This is the link for google pay sample project: https://github.com/payeezy/google_pay. So please help us to solve this.

```
 val transaction = PaymentsUtil.createTransaction(price)
    val request = PaymentsUtil.createPaymentDataRequest(transaction)
    futurePayTask = mPaymentsClient.loadPaymentData(request)
    // Since loadPaymentData may show the UI asking the user to select a payment method, we use
    // AutoResolveHelper to wait for the user interacting with it. Once completed,
    // onActivityResult will be called with the result.
    AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask<PaymentData>(futurePayTask, this, LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Please tell me how to close the dialog programmatically.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you should be able to close google pay dialogs

Comment: but there is no method defined in google pay to close the dialog.so that i posted here.

Comment: I know this is old. But if you have found a solution for this kindly update. I am going through the same scenario